# I'm trying to define an instance of Functor for my Tree datatype in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning about functors this afternoon and am trying to write one for a tree data type I just wrote up.

```
data GTree a = Node a [GTree a] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)  

instance Functor GTree where
        fmap f n [] = f n
        fmap f n a = f n fmap a
```

I'm trying to write it so that if the list is empty, map over the single node. Otherwise, recursively map over the list. Here's the error I get.

> ```
> The equation(s) for `fmap' have three arguments,
> but its type `(a -> b) -> GTree a -> GTree b' has only two
> In the instance declaration for `Functor GTree'
> ```

I understand that I have too many arguments for fmap, but I can't figure out how to write this out so that it reflects what I want it to do.

If anybody could help me out with this it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
Here's one possible solution I found, I don't really understand it though.

```
instance Functor GTree where
    fmap f (Node a ts) = Node (f a) (map (fmap f) ts)
```

Comment: You need to use the constructor: `fmap f (Node n []) = ...`

Comment: @luqui Thanks for the comment. That makes sense. I tried changing that line to fmap f (Node n []) = Node (f n) and comment out the second one for now but I'm still getting errors.

Comment: `Node` takes two arguments, you have only given it one.  Needs to be `Node (f n) []`.  Don't give up, especially regarding the left-associative application (`f x y = (f x) y`), that can take some getting used to.

Comment: Cool, thank you for pointing this stuff out to me. I'm very new to haskell so it's kind of melting my brain. I'll definitely stick with it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What fmap does is it takes a function with type `a -> b` plus a box of `a` and it'll return box of `b`. Instead of `n []` and `n a` you should use `(Node a [])` and `(Node a xs)`, which will match against Node without any children and Node with children.

```
instance Functor GTree where
        fmap f (Node a xs) = Node (f a) (fmap (fmap f) xs)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh, that solution I found totally makes sense now. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me!

Comment: You don't really need two cases here ... `map` works fine for empty list.

Comment: I am an fmap > map bigot. Therefore it should totally be 'fmap (fmap f) xs'

Comment: @Robert, as long as you're doing that, use it like a Semantic Editor Combinator:  `(fmap.fmap) f xs`, which you can see as spelling out the path to the `a` through two functors.  I'm sure we have lost Cody at this point :-P

Comment: @luqui Yes you are right of course, it should really be written that way for extreme clarity and good practise. Cody here is the article that we are referring to: http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators/

Comment: @Robert
Thanks for the link. I'm gonna drink some coffee this morning and then read up on that.

@Luqui
Definitely lost me a little haha. I'm going to be studying up on haskell all afternoon and evening, so maybe it will make more sense by the end of the day.

Thanks again to everyone for pointing out the best coding practices and helping me to understand all of this.